# Can I automatically generate a list of data values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Let's say I create an enumerable `data` set (or two) in Haskell.

```
data Note = C | CsDb | D | DsEb | E | F | FsGb | G | GsAb | A | AsBb | B deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord)
data Diatonic = Unison | Min2 | Maj2 | Min3 | Maj3 | Per4 | Tritone | Per5 | Min6 | Maj6 | Min7 | Maj7 | Octave deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord)
```

I'd like to have access to a list of these values, and this is the only way I know how:

```
notes :: [Note]
notes = [C, CsDb, D, DsEb, E, F, FsGb, G, GsAb, A, AsBb, B]

diatonics :: [Diatonic]
diatonics = [Unison, Min2, Maj2, Min3, Maj3, Per4, Tritone, Per5, Min6, Maj6, Min7, Maj7, Octave]
```

This seems like redundant boilerplate.  Is this the only way to create such a list, or can Haskell do it for me somehow?

Comment: note that this is not a list of data-types - it's still a list of values - maybe you should change the title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you add automatic `deriving` for [`Enum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) and [`Bounded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) it's as easy as:

```
data Note = C | CsDb | D | DsEb | E | F | FsGb | G | GsAb | A | AsBb | B
          deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

notes :: [Note]
notes = [minBound .. maxBound]
```

example:

```
λ> notes
[C,CsDb,D,DsEb,E,F,FsGb,G,GsAb,A,AsBb,B]
```

I'll guess you will know how to do the other ;)

---

you need the `Enum` for the `[ .. ]` syntax and `Bounded` for `minBound` and `maxBound` - so you don't have to use `Bounded` if you don't want but in this case you have to add the *bounds* yourself:

```
data Note = C | CsDb | D | DsEb | E | F | FsGb | G | GsAb | A | AsBb | B
          deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)

notes :: [Note]
notes = [C .. B]
```